# extjs paging toolbar

Tags: extjs

i am using extJs paging tool bar with store or grid panel ,it works fine with records .

when if there are no records in database,and after receive jsson data.it does,nt display proper number of records which will be zero .please give me solution

Comment: What is the JSON returned from the server if there are no records present? Also, what is number displayed at Paging Bar in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

You must have the total number of rows calculated in the controller part, to have a result as this one:

`{success:true,"total":1,"result":[{"id":"2","MyColumn1":"blabla","MyColumn2":"blibli"}]}`

Where total is number of rows

Can you give us your code and the json result that it's given to your store

Comment: user954156... I have a similar issue...can I manually implement a count and return the total or do I have to return the success part in the controller too.. in other words can I get away with just returning "total" by doing count